# iOS swift getting issue firebase crash analytics library installing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

[image: please see attached screenshot of error]

I'm getting an issue on installing Firebase crash analytic library. Please check and give me solution of error.

Comment: Without seeing your pod file, it's tough to guess for me. But in my application when i Just use  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics' it works and install other related firebase libraries.

Comment: Please provide your podfile

Comment: please see attach link https://prnt.sc/vpswv5

Comment: Hello can you please give me any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Google` and `Google/SignIn` from the Podfile.

The Google pod is deprecated and incompatible with recent versions of Firebase.

Comment: i have removed Google and google/SignIn from podfile but still same issue

Comment: Please add the Podfile to the question.

Comment: its resolved i have removed Google from podfile thank you paul